# Install PetSc on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, petsc

Hello I'm trying to install PetSc on Windows11 with MSyS2 using the tutorial. But when I'm trying to do the last step of the installation using this line :
" $  /usr/bin/python ./configure --with-mpiexec='/C/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ MPI/Bin/mpiexec' --with-shared-libraries=0 "
I got this error :
" /usr/bin/python.exe: can't open file '/home/alexa/./configure': [Errno 2] No such file or directory "

I'm a bit lost I try to find the configure file but only find it in PetSc. However I don't know how to run the configure command with MSyS2

Thx for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution the problem was i installed Petsc out of the MSys2 directory. I had to use the git command of petsc in the MSys2 prompt then use a cd~petsc to use the line : " $ /usr/bin/python ./configure --with-mpiexec='/C/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ MPI/Bin/mpiexec' --with-shared-libraries=0 " inside the petsc directory the installation did well for me hope it will help !!